# React-Testing: Debug, why this jest snapshot test is failing for a component using Material UI's Grid

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have a reusable component using Material UI Grid containers.  I have a simple snapshot test in jest and am receiving the message

```
Summary of all failing tests
 FAIL  src/components/Form/__tests__/FormContentGrid.node.js
  ● renders correctly

    Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `xs` of `Grid` must be used on `item`.
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid))

      11 |       </LabelWrapper>
      12 |     </Grid>
    > 13 |     <Grid container spacing={1} xs={10}>
         |     ^
      14 |       {children}
      15 |     </Grid>
      16 |   </Grid>
```

Here is the component the test is written for:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { LabelWrapper, SideLabel } from './components';

const FormContentGrid = ({ label, children }) => (
  <Grid container spacing={1}>
    <Grid item xs={1}>
      <LabelWrapper>
        <SideLabel>{label}</SideLabel>
      </LabelWrapper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container spacing={1} xs={10}>
      {children}
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
);

FormContentGrid.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node,
};

export default FormContentGrid;
```

Here is the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import FormContentGrid from '../FormContentGrid';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const component = shallow(<FormContentGrid label="test" />);

  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I'm trying to figure out why the test is failing and how to fix it

Comment: According to the warning you're getting: you can only use the `xs` prop on `<Grid item>` and not on `<Grid container>`

Comment: Strange, it is needed in the Grid container and seems like it can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the way to get around this is to set item equal to true in the container.

```
<Grid container spacing={1} xs={10} item={true}>
```

Comment: It should be done as `<Grid item spacing={1} xs={10}>`